# How to reload contents of Ext.Window

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a window and a dataview inside it-

```
if (!win) {
    var dataview = new Ext.DataView({

    });    
    var win = new Ext.Window({
        ...
        ...
        items: dataview 
    });
    this.win=win;
}

var dview = this.win.items.itemAt(0);
dview.title = 'My view'; 
this.win.show();
```

However, the title do not display at first when window is shown but displays in second run. I am thinking of reloading window before showing. Any help?

Comment: i think you have to call refresh() after change title

Comment: You are setting a title on the dview. The dataview doesn't have a title bar. Do you want to set a title on the window or the dataview?

Comment: here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vkVu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('PowerTrainCopy', {
    extend: 'Ext.Window',
    id: 'copyPTWin',
    height:450,
    width: 1110,
    modal:true,
    title: 'Copy Powertrain',
    //plain: true,
    border: true,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    closable: true,
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    items: []
});

copyPTWin = Ext.create('PowerTrainCopy');
copyPTWin.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Within items u can use:

```
xtype: 'dataview',
title: '',
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to display different titles depending upon condition.